# Show Multiline View in GridView

Tags: asp.net

I have Stored a Data in database by multiline Textbox.. 
When i link it with the gridview.. It shows that data in a Single line.. I cant get the multiline view.. please give ur valuable suggestions for that.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hai Siva is it your text is binded to a label control on databind in that gridview...

Comment: No.. I just put my DataTable object to GridView.DataSourse

Comment: SqlDataAdapter d = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from forum order by Sno desc", (SqlConnection)Application["con"]);
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        d.Fill(t);
        GridView1.DataSource = t;
        GridView1.DataBind();

Database forum having the multiline text.. But it is view as single line in dridview..

Answer (score 0):

one solution could be replace "new line" char/string with "
" tag, in multiline text. Then bind this text in GridView cell.